# Azure Pipelines: How to make a task dependent on a previous task?

Tags: windows, testing, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure-Pipelines for my CI integration on windows-2019. Here's a scenario, the task #'s mean order in which they occur (1 being first).

In task 2, I am running tests. In task 3, I want to generate a report on these tests, regardless if the tests succeeded or failed (thus adding - `condition: succeededOrFailed()` to task 3).

However, in task 1, I am building the repo. If the build fails, I don't want any subsequent tasks to run. But since task 3 has `condition: succeededOrFailed()`, it still runs and produces another error. My goal is to have task 3 run regardless if task 2 fails or succeeds, but not if task 1 fails.

I'm not sure the best way to handle this. Is it possible to make task 3 dependent on task 2? Or can I stop the whole pipeline immediately if task 1 fails?

Also, for task 1, I tried `continueOnError: false` because I thought it would stop the pipeline there, but it didn't do what I thought. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Testing it out now, will update soon, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My goal is to have task 3 run regardless if task 2 fails or succeeds, but not if task 1 fails.

From your requirement, you can connect task 3 and task 1.

Here is the Yaml template:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: task1
...


- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task.A.status]Success"      
  condition: succeeded()

- task: task2
 ...
  condition: succeeded()

- task: task 3
....
  condition: and (succeededOrFailed(), eq(variables['task.A.status'], 'success'))
```

**Explaination：**

The `Powershell task` is used to set an `output variable` for task 1.  When task 1 success, the variable will set the value `success`. This variable could be used in the following tasks.

The condition in task 2 depends on task 1.

The condition in task 3 needs to meet two conditions **at the same time**. (1. no matter success or fail , 2. The custom variable value is success).

Then the task 3 will run only when the task 1 success. And task 3 will run regardless if task 2 fails or succeeds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correction? Then the task 2 will run only when the task 1 success

Answer (score 1):

Azure pipelines provides dependsOn: Here is an example from the docs:

```
jobs:

- job: Foo
  steps:
  - script: echo Hello!
    condition: always() # this step will always run, even if the pipeline is canceled

- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  condition: failed() # this job will only run if Foo fails
```

If condition is not specified the default is Foo succeeded.