# How can I add condition for when a Pull Request is closed in Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to destroy some temporary infrastructure (review apps) when a PR is closed using Azure Devops Yaml pipeline files.

How can i implement a condition to trigger a pipeline when a Pull request is closed in azure-pipelines.yaml ?

The repos are in github and the pipeline YAML file is in Azure Devops

im confused. basically this is what i have already and want to add a delete stage based on the pr number and if its closed  :
pr:
branches:
include:
- master

trigger:
branches:
include:

- master
- stage: CreateTempReviewAPP
  condition: ne(variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber'], '')
  jobs:

  - job: DeployReview
  - stage: DelReviewAPP
    condition: if pull requestnumber -=123 and pr status = closed or merged
    jobs:
  - job:DestroyReview

Comment: Do you want to run the pipeline only when the PR is completed successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i implement a condition to trigger a pipeline when a Pull request is closed in azure-pipelines.yaml ?

I think this question can be divided into two parts:

1. How to start a pipeline in a task?
2. How to trigger a task after a pull request is completed in pipeline?

**For the part 1:**

You can use the REST API [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Here is an example to call this REST API in a PowerShell task. Please replace the `{PAT}` with your own variable:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "{PAT}"
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline id}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
      $body = @'
      {
      }
      '@
      $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

**For the part 2:**

If your pipeline is linear, then this step is unnecessary. You just need to add the PowerShell task after the task that close the pull request, and then the pipeline will run in sequence.

If not, you can use conditions. Here are an example to use conditions in jobs level:

```
jobs:
- job: closepr
  displayName: Close the pull request
  steps:
  ...

- job: triggerpipeline
  dependsOn: closepr
  condition: succeeded()
  displayName: Trigger a pipeline
  steps:
  ...
```

You can also use conditions in tasks level. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62441544/14026068) for the detailed steps.

**Update:**

I supposed that what you want to do is to set the below condition:

```
condition: if pull requestnumber -=123 and pr status = closed or merged
```

Firstly, there isn't a predefined variable that has the information of pull request status. The variables starting with `System.PullRequest` can only read the pull request data that triggered the pipeline. They cannot read the pull request data of a specific ID.

However, you can use REST API to get it. Here is an example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Call REST API and set the result to $pr
      $token = "{PAT}" # Replace it with your PAT
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pull request id}?api-version=7.1-preview.1" # Replace the {} with your information
      $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
      $pr = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get  -Headers $head -ContentType application/json
      # Pass the status result to future tasks. You can also pass it to future jobs/stages.
      $status = $pr.status
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prstatus;]$status"

- task: ... # The task you use to destroy apps
  condition: eq(variables.prstatus, 'completed')
  ...
```

So that the second task will run only if the pull request is completed.

If you want to pass the status variable to future **jobs**, please refer to [output variables set in a future job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs).

If you want to pass it to future **stages**, please refer to [output variables set in future stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages).

Comment: ive added more details of what is required in the main question